# Using R/Markdown fails inside learnr question

Tags: r, r-markdown, r-exams, learnr

**Motivation:** I want to write an interface that uses questions from the R package [exams](http://www.R-exams.org/) in [learnr](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/) questions/quizzes. In R/exams each question is either an R/Markdown (Rmd) or R/LaTeX (Rnw) file with a certain structure specifying question, solution, and further meta-information. The questions can contain R code to make them dynamic, e.g., sampling numbers or certain text building blocks etc. Hence, the workflow is that first the questions are run through `knitr::knit` or `utils::Sweave` and then embedded in a suitable output format.

**Problem:** When I `rmarkdown::run("learnr+rexams.Rmd")` a learnr tutorial that dynamically produces a question or quiz from an Rmd exercise I get the error:

> Error in if (grepl(not_valid_char_regex, label)) { :
> argument is of length zero

The code for a simple reproducible example `learnr+rexams.Rmd` is included below.
The reason for the error appears to be that learnr runs a function `verify_tutorial_chunk_label()` that tries to assure the the learnr R chunk labels are well formatted. However, confusion is caused by the chunks that are run by the R/exams package, unnecessarily leading to the error above.

**Workarounds:** I can disable the `verify_tutorial_chunk_label()` in the learnr namespace and then everything works well. Or I can use Rnw instead of Rmd exercises and then learnr does not conflict with `Sweave()`. Also, when I run my code outside of a learnr tutorial it works fine.

**Question:** Can I do anything less invasive to make `exams` cooperate with `learnr`? For example, setting some appropriate `knitr` options or something like that?

**Example:** This is the source for the minimal learnr tutorial `learnr+rexams.Rmd` that replicates the problem. Note that everything is very much simplified and only works for certain R/exams exercises, here using the [function](http://www.R-exams.org/templates/function/) exercise template that ships with R/exams.

````
---
title: "learnr & R/exams"
output: learnr::tutorial
runtime: shiny_prerendered
---

```{r exams2learnr, include = FALSE}
exams2learnr <- function(file) {
  x <- exams::xexams(file)[[1]][[1]]
  x <- list(text = x$question, type = "learnr_text",
    learnr::answer(x$metainfo$solution, correct = TRUE))
  do.call(learnr::question, x)
}
## assignInNamespace("verify_tutorial_chunk_label", function() return(), ns = "learnr")
```

```{r rfunctions, echo = FALSE, message = FALSE}
exams2learnr("function.Rmd")
```
````

Running this tutorial (as noted above) replicates the error. To avoid it I can either uncomment the `assignInNamespace()` call *or alternatively* replace `"function.Rmd"` by `"function.Rnw"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that by the time `learnr::question()` is called, knitr is no longer able to find the chunk label for the chunk where `exams2learnr()` was called. You can get around this by setting the current chunk label before calling `do.call(learnr_question, x)`:

```
exams2learnr <- function(file, label = knitr::opts_current$get("label")) {
  force(label)
  x <- exams::xexams(file)[[1]][[1]]
  x <- list(
    text = x$question, 
    type = "learnr_text",
    learnr::answer(x$metainfo$solution, correct = TRUE)
  )
  knitr::opts_current$set(label = label)
  do.call(learnr::question, x)
}
```

This also lets you set the `label` dynamically if you want, which becomes the ID of the question in learnr.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks! I had tried to propagate the knitr label but had tried only variants that did not work (before calling learnr::quiz but not each learnr::question). Now I understand why. Also the pointer that label= could be an argument is good, I have incorporated that into my code now.

Comment: Thanks to this answer I could now finish the first draft of the `exams2learnr` package, including the full function `exams2learnr()`. It is not yet on CRAN but can be easily installed from R-Forge: `install.packages("exams2learnr", repos = "https://R-Forge.R-project.org")`. See also: <https://R-Forge.R-project.org/R/?group_id=1337>